# How to put an external parameter in array.prototype.some()

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to implement a prime number list calculator, my code involves asking for a number, and it should print all prime numbers from 1 to the number. It involves calculating the square root of the number chosen, calculate all prime numbers between 1 and the square root(i find them with a function and I create an array). After that we'll now that a number will be prime if its not divisible for any of the numbers in the array, so I thought to use array.some to see with a for cycle if the number is divisible (and not equal) to any of those in the array. Then I put the value of the prime numbers in a string and I return the string. My problem is that I dont know how to use the number i want to check into array.some, because in class they only though us how to use it without external parameters. If you can also provide an explanation on how to put external parameters in methods of prototype.array I'll be very thankful.

```
function prime(n){
    switch(n){
        case 0: return false
        case 1: return true
        case 2: return true
        default:{
        if(n%2==0)return false
        if(n<0)return false

          for(let inc=3;inc<=n;inc+=2){
            if(n%inc==0 && n==inc)return true

            if(n%inc==0 && n!=inc)return false
          }
        }  
      }
}

function rangeprime(a,b){
let result = []
  if(1<=a<=3){result = [1,2];a = 3}

  if(a%2==0)a+=1

  for(let i=a;i<=b;i+=2){
    if(prime(i))result.push(i)
  }
 
  return result

let n = Number(prompt(`n?`))
  let sqn = Math.sqrt(n).toFixed(0)
  result = ''
  range = rangeprime(1,sqn)
  const into = (element,i)=>i%element==0&&i!=element
  

  for(let i = 1;i<=n;i+=2){
    if(!(range.some(into.bind(i)))){
      result+=`${i}, `}
    };console.log(result)
}
```

Comment: after return kwd your code is not accessible anymore - firstly... then you can use any external variables inside functions and their sub-functions, ie all defined vars defined previously up to the global scope

Comment: The argument to .some is a function.  Currently you have it defined as `into`, but you can write your own intermediate function that calls `into` instead.  `!range.some(prime => into(prime, i));`

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the variables that are in the same scope so:

```js
const a = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6]
const b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
const c = 3

console.log('do', a.join(''), 'has', c, a.some(e => e === c))
console.log('do', b.join(''), 'has', c, b.some(e => e === c))
```

In your example - just move the function to the loop:

```
for(let i = 1;i<=n;i+=2){
  if(!(range.some(into.some((element,i)=>i%element==0&&i!=element))){
    result+=`${i}, `}
  };
}
```